how to recover the history scroll position when using VariableSizeList
I am using a React window "react-window": "^1.8.10" to render some PDF pages, this is what the code looks like:
const renderPdfList = () => {
  if (pdf && pageViewports) {
    return (
      <AutoSizer onResize={onResize}>
        {({ width, height }: { width: number; height: number }) => (
          <VariableSizeList
            ref={virtualListRef}
            width={width}
            height={height}
            estimatedItemSize={50}
            itemCount={pdf.numPages}
            itemSize={(pageIndex) => getPageHeight(pageIndex, width)}
          >
            {({ index, style }: { index: number; style: any }) => (
              <TeXPDFPage
                index={index + 1}
                width={width}
                style={style}
                projId={projId}
              />
            )}
          </VariableSizeList>
        )}
      </AutoSizer>
    );
  } else {
    return <div>loading...</div>;
  }
};

This is what the react-pdf "react-pdf": "^9.1.0" Document code looks like:
<Document
    options={options}
    file={curPdfUrl!}
    // className={styles.pdfDocument}
    onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}
  >
    <div
      id="pdfContainer"
      ref={divRef}
      style={{
        height: "100vh",
        width: "100vw",
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        overflow: "hidden",
        flex: 1,
      }}
      onClick={openPdfUrlLink}
      onScroll={(e) => handlePdfScroll(e)}
    >
      {renderPdfList()}
    </div>
  </Document>

Now I need to scroll to the last scroll position, I have tried like this on the document load success:
const onDocumentLoadSuccess = (pdf: DocumentCallback) => {
  const { numPages } = pdf;
  setPageNum(numPages);
  setPdf(pdf);
  // go to the last pdf position
  let cachedPage = localStorage.getItem(
    readConfig("pdfCurPage") + curProjInfo?.main.project_id
  );
  if (cachedPage && Number(cachedPage)) {
    scrollToPage(Number(cachedPage), virtualListRef);
  }
};

but on the document load success function, the virtualListRef is undefined. Is it possible to restore to the last scroll position of the PDF?
